# CTest custom target for python scripts with arguments

Tags: python, cmake, ctest

I would like to be able to run some python unit tests apart from other tests by means of  CTest and the following command:

```
make unit_tests
```

I tried the following combination but it does not work:

```
ADD_TEST(unit_test_1 ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/unit_test_1.py --verbose)

ADD_TEST(unit_test_2 ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/unit_test_2.py --verbose)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(unit_tests COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} 
                             DEPENDS unit_test_1 unit_test_2)
```

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (I replaced the test commands with some dummy statements, but adjusting it to invoke python should be doable):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

enable_testing()

add_test(unit_test_1 echo "Unit test 1")
add_test(unit_test_2 echo "Unit test 2")

add_custom_target(unit_tests COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND})
```

No need to add any dependencies to the `unit_tests` target. By default, ctest runs all tests.

Comment: Thank you! However, I cannot use your solution because it will run all tests while I want to run only some tests (the unit ones).

Comment: Then use `ctest -R unit_test_1` to e.g. run one particular test.

Comment: Tests are supposed to be managed automatically. Your solution requires a manual management of them.